# monitor calibration fail

Tags: display, colors, gnome-color-manager, monitor-calibration

To color calibrate a monitor, I use a color measuring tool that shows up as USB device X-Rite, Inc. i1 Display Pro.

It works on one system (22.04), on another it fails at the first test patch:
Calibration failed! internal error

gnome-color-manager and argyll are installed and re-installed

The graphics of the laptop where calibration fails is Mesa Intel Xe.

What can I do?